# Dropping a table with all its dependencies (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I drop a table with all its dependencies [SPs, Views, etc.] (Microsoft SQL Server) without knowing its dependencies upfront? I know I can display all dependencies in Mangement Studio but I'm searching for utility script that I could simply speficy an object and it would drop this object with all its dependencies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER 2005: Drop all the tables, stored procedures, triggers, constriants and all the dependencies in one sql statement.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536350/sql-server-2005-drop-all-the-tables-stored-procedures-triggers-constriants-an)

Comment: Accepted answer of this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812889/drop-cascade-in-sql-server) gives you direction. Though it is in different language.

Comment: @wallyk, it is not duplicate. The question there is to `delete everything`, this question is about `deleting everything dependent on one table`.

Comment: @Oded It needs to be done anyway I guess :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The best thing to do it is "Generate scripts for Drop"

Select Database -> Right Click -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts - will open wizard for generating scripts

- Select the database -> next
- Set option 'Script to create' to true (want to create)
- Set option 'Script to Drop' to true (want to drop)
- Set option 'Generate script for dependent object' to true -> Next
- Select the Check box to select objects wish to create script
- Select the choice to write script (File, New window, Clipboard)

Execute the script

This way we can customize our script i.e., we can do scripting for selected objects of a database.

I hope this will help you!

Best Wishes, JP

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Sp_Depends` to find the dependencies. With that you can modify [the script from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536350/sql-server-2005-drop-all-the-tables-stored-procedures-triggers-constriants-an) Maybe someone less lazy than me will do that for you.

Note: Each object of course could have its own dependencies so you'll need to process them as well.

Comment: Or maybe someone *more* lazy actually... :)

Comment: Looks like there is no one less lazy than you! I guess I will accept your answer then...

Answer (score 2):

Delete a SQL object using its schema-qualified name. For tables, the constraints are dropped first.
Errors are ignored.

```
create procedure [dbo].[spDropObject] (@fullname nvarchar(520))
as
begin
    begin try
        declare @type nvarchar(5)
        declare @resolvedFullname nvarchar(520) 
        declare @resolvedName nvarchar(255) 
        set @type = null
        set @resolvedFullname = null
        set @resolvedName = null

        --find the object
        select 
        @type = o.[type] 
        ,@resolvedFullname = '[' + object_schema_name(o.id) +  '].[' + o.[name] + ']'
        ,@resolvedName = '[' + o.[name] + ']'
        from dbo.sysobjects o
        where id = object_id(@fullname)

        --PROCEDURE
        if(@type = 'P') 
        begin
            exec('drop procedure ' + @resolvedFullname);
            return;
        end

        --VIEW
        if(@type = 'V') 
        begin
            exec('drop view ' + @resolvedFullname);
            return;
        end

        --FUNCTION
        if(@type = 'FN' or @type = 'TF') 
        begin
            exec('drop function ' + @resolvedFullname);
            return;
        end

        --TRIGGER
        if(@type = 'TF') 
        begin
            exec('drop trigger ' + @resolvedFullname);
            return;
        end

        --CONSTRAINT
        if(@type = 'C' or @type = 'UQ' or @type = 'D' or @type = 'F' or @type = 'PK' or @type = 'K') 
        begin
            declare @fullTablename nvarchar(520);
            set @fullTablename = null

            --find the contraint's table
            select @fullTablename ='[' + object_schema_name(t.[object_id]) + '].[' + t.[Name] + ']'
            from sys.tables t
            join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
            where t.object_id = (select parent_obj from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(@resolvedFullname))

            exec('alter table ' + @fullTablename + ' drop constraint ' + @resolvedName);
            return; 
        end

        --TABLE (drop all constraints then drop the table)
        if(@type = 'U') 
        begin
            --find FK references to the table
            declare @fktab table([Name] nvarchar(255))
            insert @fktab 
            select 
            [Name] = '[' + object_name(fkc.[constraint_object_id]) + ']'
            /*
            ,[Parent] = '[' + object_schema_name(fkc.[parent_object_id]) +  '].[' + object_name(fkc.[parent_object_id]) + ']'
            ,[Ref] = '[' + object_schema_name(fkc.[referenced_object_id]) +  '].[' + object_name(fkc.[referenced_object_id]) + ']'
            */
            from sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc
            where referenced_object_id = object_id(@resolvedFullname)
            order by [Name]

            --iterate FKs
            while(1=1)
            begin
                declare @constraint nvarchar(255)
                set @constraint = null
                select top 1
                @constraint = [Name]
                from @fktab

                if(@constraint is not null)
                begin
                    --drop FK constraint
                    exec [dbo].[spDropObject] @constraint;
                    delete from @fktab where [Name] = @constraint --remove current record from working table
                end
                else break;
            end         

            --find constraints for table
            declare @constraintTab table ([Name] nvarchar(255));

            insert @constraintTab
            select [name] 
            from sys.objects 
            where parent_object_id = object_id(@resolvedFullname)
            order by [name]

            --iterate constraints
            while(1=1)
            begin
                set @constraint = null;
                select top 1 @constraint = [Name] from @constraintTab

                if(@constraint is not null)
                begin
                    --drop constraint
                    exec [dbo].[spDropObject] @constraint;
                    delete from @constraintTab where [Name] = @constraint --remove current record from working table
                end
                else break;
            end

            --drop table
            exec('drop table ' + @resolvedFullname);
            return;
        end
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @message nvarchar(max)
        set @message = error_message( ) ;
        print @message
    end catch
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I specifically wanted to drop a specified table and the tables that depend on that table. It wasn't useful to me to only drop the foreign key constraints that reference it. I wrote a stored procedure to do this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropDependentTables (
  @tableName NVARCHAR(64))
AS
-- Find and drop all tables that depend on @tableName
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT *
  FROM sys.foreign_keys
  WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = @tableName AND
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) != @tableName)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dependentTableName NVARCHAR(64)
  SELECT TOP 1 @dependentTableName = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = @tableName AND
      OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) != @tableName

    EXEC DropDependentTables @dependentTableName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave a late answer (after around 10 years). I hope you'll find it handy.

In our company, we use this script to properly delete database tables. For each table, we first drop the dependencies (REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS) then delete the table itself.

```
USE [database-name]

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(500) DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + tc2.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' +  tc2.TABLE_NAME + '] DROP [' + rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME + '];'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc1
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc2 ON tc2.CONSTRAINT_NAME =rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME

OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
Exec sp_executesql @Sql
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
END

CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
GO

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
GO
```

*The credit goes to a colleague of mine, [Abolfazl Najafzade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5954471/abn-najaf), for the script.*